# Magento 2.3.0 How to get request parameters in event observer?

Tags: module, event-observer, review, magento2.3.0, request

I would like to get a request parameter in the observer file.

Below is the observer code.

> etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<event name="review_save_before">
    <observer name="set_customer_data" instance="Namespace\Modulename\Observer\ReviewSaveBeforeObserver"/>
</event>
```

> Observer/ReviewSaveBeforeObserver

```
<?php
namespace Namespace\Modulename\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Review\Model\Review;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class ReviewSaveBeforeObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    /**
     * @var Http
     */
    private $request;

    /**
     * @var OrderInterface
     */
    private $orderInterface;

    /** @var \Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog */
    protected $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $loggerInterface,
        OrderInterface $orderInterface,
        Http $request
    ) {
        $this->logger = $loggerInterface;
        $this->orderInterface = $orderInterface;
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    /**
     * This is the method that fires when the event runs.
     *
     * @param Observer $observer
     */
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $this->logger->addDebug('Executed Review Save After Observer');

        /** @var Review $review */
        $review = $observer->getDataByKey('object');
        echo '<pre>';print_r($this->request->getParams());die;
        //$review->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_APPROVED);            
        $review->setCustomerId(1);        
    }
}
```

But it is throwing below error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in /var/www/html/CE/2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php on line 3955 in /var/www/html/CE/2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php:61 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\App\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', '/var/www/html/C...', 3955, Array) #1 /var/www/html/CE/2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/DB/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(3955): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256) #2 [internal function]: Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql->__destruct() #3 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/CE/2.3.0/vendor/magento/framework/App/ErrorHandler.php on line 61

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: code looks fine. Are you sure error generated becoz of using $this->request only or it can be something else ?

Comment: Yes, it is a generating error due to `getParamas()`

Comment: Using this observer I want to set the customer ID from the request params, if I pass static value then it is working fine.

Comment: I think using `getParams()` will not throw error `Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back`, Try this, use `RequestInterface` object and get only params from the object without doing any other operation. You can put this code in  `try.. catch` to get exact error details.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. and especially `Jaimin Sutariya` and `Yash Shah`. My issue is resolved. I do not dam sure what is the reason for this issue because I have a 2 issue in my code. 1) I print in the observer and 2) I have used OrderInterface to get value in Observer. after removing OrderInterface & print_r(). my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you have printed information in the observer. I think it is not because you have used `getRequest()` in the observer.

Try to see the result in this way.

```
$writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/test.log');
$logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
$logger->addWriter($writer);
$logger->info(print_r($this->request->getParams(), true));
```

And check in the test.log file. Do not print anything in the observer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this way:

```
/**
 * @var \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
 */
public $request;

public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
){
    ...
    $this->request = $request;
}

public function execute(Observer $observer)
{
    $post = $this->request->getPost();
                /* or */
    $param = $this->request->getParam('parameter');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface::getParams()
```

In replacement for:

```
\Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http::getParams()
```

Comment: Thanks, I already try this but it is not working. get params working fine in the controller, but it is not working in Observer. I just want to to know why it is not working in the observer?

Comment: I'm not really sure as error is actually not related, can you try to comment this `$review = $observer->getDataByKey('object');` in your current code and check.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with :

```
//\Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface
$this->_request->getParam('field_name');
```

Its working for me. Hope it will work for you too.